# PHP :passing message along header location

Tags: php

I would like to show a message on the page once the user enter some wrong data

so far I am passing a message like

```
    $Message = "Some error occured please try after some time ";
    header("Location:index.php?Message={$Message}");
```

I know this message will display only in address bar so what should I do so that this message could display on the index.php page instead of this

```
http://localhost/UI/index.php?Message=Someerror occured please try after some time
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
if( !empty( $_REQUEST['Message'] ) )
{
    echo sprintf( '<p>%s</p>', $_REQUEST['Message'] );
}
```

???

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` without `echo` every time.  Where did the `<p>` tags come from?

Answer (score 11):

use `urlencode()`

```
$Message = urlencode("Some error occured please try after some time ");
header("Location:index.php?Message=".$Message);
die;
```

and on `index.php`:

```
if(isset($_GET['Message'])){
    echo $_GET['Message'];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is already answered years ago, I had similar problem so I found this answer... wouldn˙t this be better. I used this code in my app, with different message and `$_GET` variable:

```
    header("Location:index.php?msg");
```

an then on `index.php`

```
    if(isset($_GET['msg']))
    {
        $message = "Some error occured please try after some time";
        echo $message;
    }
```

That way URL is much cleaner, and `header` code is used as trigger for `if` loop.